# Parsing Data From Axios Get Request in React

Tags: reactjs, json, parsing

I'm pretty new to React, so apologies if this is a dumb question, but I'm having a lot of trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong. I have a small project that gets weather conditions of ski resorts and returns the conditions to the user.

When I try to parse the response from the weather API in my `Resort` class with this code `<h3>temp: {res.main.temp} </h3>`, I get this error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')`. When I try `<h3>temp: {res.main} </h3>` I get an error stating `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {temp, feels_like, temp_min, temp_max, pressure, humidity}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.` I get that I can't just return an array, but I can't understand why I'm getting the 1st error message when I parse for `temp` since the 2nd error message makes it clear that `temp` is a valid key. Even my `console.log('temp: ', response.data.main.temp)` test gives me the temperature. I would like to be able to parse more than just 1 field from the response, so I don't want to do `setRes(response.data.main.temp)`. Would appreciate any help. Here's what I have so far:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Resort from './Resort';

const resorts = new Map()
resorts.set("Keystone", [39.6069742, -105.97011])
resorts.set("Breckenridge", [39.4808, -106.0676])
const appId = "key_goes_here";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    {[...resorts.keys()].map((item)=>{
      return <Resort resortName={item} lat={resorts.get(item)[0]} lon={resorts.get(item)[1]} appid={appId} />
    })}
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Resort.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather'

function Resort(props) {
    const [res, setRes] = React.useState([])
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url, { params: {lat: props.lat, lon: props.lon, appid: props.appid, units: "imperial"}}).then((response) => {
            setRes(response.data)
            console.log('temp: ', response.data.main.temp)
        });
    }, [props]);

    if (!res) return null;

    return (
        <div className='Resort'>
            <h1>{props.resortName}</h1>
            <h3>Lat: {props.lat} Lon: {props.lon}</h3>
            <h3>temp: {res.main.temp} </h3>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Resort;
```